# LDAP Filter memberof

Tags: ldap

Hallo I need help to optimize a LDAP Filter string because the Ldap filter is too long (maximum is 255 characters) for my tool (Foreman).
My LDAP curent Ldap filter

```
(|
   (memberOf=cn=admingoup,ou=groups,OU=admin,DC=xxx,DC=de)
   (memberOf=CN=group1,OU=dd,OU=cc,OU=ab,DC=xxx,DC=de)
   (memberOf=CN=group2,OU=dd,OU=cc,OU=ab,DC=xxx,DC=de)
)
```

This work but i need a soultion like

```
(|
   (memberOf=cn=admingoup,ou=groups,OU=admin,DC=xxx,DC=de)
   (memberOf=CN=*,OU=dd,OU=cc,OU=ab,DC=xxx,DC=de)
)
```

Comment: Should work, as long as you don't care what `*` matches. Unclear what you're asking, or why.

Comment: Usually, memberOf has DN syntax and no subtring matching rule.

Comment: yes memberOf with * dont work

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can work your way out without making modifications on your constraints somewhere :

- Allow longer filter in foreman
- Modify the LDAP directory to allow substring match on the `memberOf` attribute
- Modify your filter. A way to do it could be :

  - search base dn : `DC=xxx,DC=de`
  - search filter : `(&(objectclass=group)(|(cn=admingroup)(cn=group1)(cn=group2)))` (This is an example, the point is to match only the group you need, maybe using the entry id if necessary)
  - attribute retrieve `member` (or the equivalent)

  What it will do is to retrieve all the members of these groups, dupplicate members should not be a probleme for access control I presume